# Trying to understand the code on sysdate function from handover work

Tags: oracle, sysdate

No problem just a question

It's not a problem, just trying to understand handover work from a previous employer.

```
    SELECT *
      FROM MISS.M42V_PERSONNEL_SERVICE_RECORDS X
      WHERE X.EQUITY_STATUS IN ('P', 'T', 'O')
      AND (X.START_DATE     < TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)+1))
      AND (X.EXPIRE_DATE   IS NULL
      OR X.EXPIRE_DATE      > SYSDATE)

TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)+1))
```

Trying to understand what the +1 after sysdate intended to do. Trying to convert this code from oracle to SQL server Management studio. SQL Server Management Studio doesn't understand the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's understand it in bits and parts:

```
select SYSDATE FROM DUAL; -- TODAY 
-- 22-08-2019 01:06:10

SELECT LAST_DAY(SYSDATE) FROM DUAL; -- LAST DAY OF THE MONTH 
-- 31-08-2019 01:06:25

SELECT LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)+1 FROM DUAL; -- +1 ADDS ONE DAY TO THE DATE 
-- FIRST DAY OF THE NEXT MONTH 
-- 01-09-2019 01:06:39

SELECT TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)+1) FROM DUAL; -- TRUNC IS USED TO REMOVE TIME PORTION
-- 01-09-2019 12:00:00
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I got that, thank you. Now how would I go about adding an extra day on SQL Server syntax version below considering the fact that I'm converting to date?  AND (X.START_DATE     < CONVERT(DATE,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),105)))

Comment: This is the error I'm getting "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int" been trying to find a workaround for this but no luck. #SSMS

Comment: I think your question is resolved and this must be the another question. Anyway try to use `AND X.START_DATE < EOMONTH(GETDATE(), 105)`

Comment: I know, my bad. Thank you very much Tejash! :)

Answer (score 0):

It will give first day for next month.
as of today if you run below query.

select (Last_Day(Sysdate)+1) from dual;

Result:
01-SEP-19

Comment: I got that, thank you. Now how would I go about adding an extra day on SQL Server syntax version below considering the fact that I'm converting to date? AND (X.START_DATE < CONVERT(DATE,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),105))

Comment: This is the error I'm getting "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int" been trying to find a workaround for this but no luck. #SSMS